# uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, applicationcontroller

When I run my rails application in development mode it runs fine.  When I run it in production mode, it doesn't start.  Instead it gives me: `uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Mailer`.  This application has been upgraded from a rails 2 application, so is there anything I could be missing or any other ideas why it wouldn't be working?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer was related to a file that wasn't suppose to be there [see this Q&A from helpsheets.co](https://www.helpsheets.co/questions/31-rails-undefined-mailer).